# Activate DataTables when placed on page via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have a DataTable that I am displaying on the page. I am over writing a  dataTable that is currently on the page with an ajax call (I am not populating the table via ajax, I am just removing the first table them placing the new table on the page from an ajax call). When I run `$("#dataTable").DataTable().destroy(); $('#dataTable').DataTable();` after the ajax call it does not seem to instantiate the new dataTable. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to add id="dataTable" to my ajax loaded table.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I forgot to add id="dataTable" to my ajax loaded table.